# Что за ошибка? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\nextcord\health_check.py:25: DistributionWarning: discord.py is installed which is incompatible with nextcord. Please remove this library by using `pip3 uninstall discord.py`
  warn(message, DistributionWarning, stacklevel=0)
C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\nextcord\health_check.py:25: DistributionWarning: discord is installed which is incompatible with nextcord. Please remove this library by using `pip3 uninstall discord`
  warn(message, DistributionWarning, stacklevel=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В тексте ошибки (мне кажется) исчерпывающая информация.

Comment: это не  из за этого, я решил проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека **Nextcore** - потомок **Discord.py**.

У них отличий мало (в плане синтаксиса кода), но всё же они есть и из-за этого компилятор тебе говорит: `"Discord.py несовместим с библиотекой Nextcore. Пожалуйста удалите её с помощью (pip uninstall discord.py)"`.